# unlock() never invoked but using try..finally

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I'm using a servlets (atmosphere framework and a custom one) which both use the same ReentrantLock to synchronize some operations. I got the confusing behavior, that a single thread enters the lock again and again without ever calling `unlock()` matching its previous `lock()`.

For debugging purposes I've added a dump of the stacktrace right after the `lock()` invokation and it always shows the very same output. Doesn't this mean, that my method is invoked again and again but the succeeding `try...finally` is never executed?

```
IManagerLock batchLock = _lockManager.getManagerLock(true);
try {
    // ...do something - in this case the code won't try to lock() again
}
finally {
    batchLock.unlock();
}
```

The `getManagerLock()` will aquire the lock and return some wrapper object around the lock which allows me to perform some debugging etc. It will e.g. assign an UUID to the wrapper object which is printed to the log on `lock()` and `unlock()`.

Here is an example of the wired stacktrace. It is repeated seven times. As you can see, there is only the `Locked: xxx` but not `Unlocked: xxx` message.

```
17:25:18,550 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) Locked: 1a59d9ea-841f-4024-9043-67c8e649c342
17:25:18,551 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) java.lang.Exception
17:25:18,551 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$LockManagerBatch.<init>(DefaultLockManager.java:377)
17:25:18,552 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager.java:246)
17:25:18,553 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
17:25:18,553 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.channel.LockChannel.onClose(LockChannel.java:128)
17:25:18,554 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:25:18,554 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
17:25:18,555 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:25:18,556 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
17:25:18,556 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.util.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:209)
17:25:18,556 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.invoke(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:335)
17:25:18,557 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:209)
17:25:18,557 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeAtmosphereHandler(AsynchronousProcessor.java:544)
17:25:18,558 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.completeLifecycle(AsynchronousProcessor.java:486)
17:25:18,558 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor.inspect(OnDisconnectInterceptor.java:77)
17:25:18,558 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeInterceptors(AsynchronousProcessor.java:340)
17:25:18,559 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:199)
17:25:18,559 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:115)
17:25:18,560 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport.service(JBossWebCometSupport.java:93)
17:25:18,560 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281)
17:25:18,560 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.event(AtmosphereServlet.java:326)
17:25:18,560 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:494)
17:25:18,560 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:399)
17:25:18,561 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:273)
17:25:18,561 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
17:25:18,561 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
17:25:18,561 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
17:25:18,562 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
17:25:18,562 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
17:25:18,562 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
17:25:18,562 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
17:25:18,562 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897)
17:25:18,563 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634)
17:25:18,563 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039)
17:25:18,563 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:25:18,567 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) Locked: 56fe9bc2-6c52-4fe4-8011-858221db4318
17:25:18,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) java.lang.Exception
17:25:18,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$LockManagerBatch.<init>(DefaultLockManager.java:377)
17:25:18,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager.java:246)
17:25:18,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
17:25:18,568 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.channel.LockChannel.onClose(LockChannel.java:128)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.util.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:209)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.invoke(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:335)
17:25:18,569 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:209)
17:25:18,570 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeAtmosphereHandler(AsynchronousProcessor.java:544)
17:25:18,570 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.completeLifecycle(AsynchronousProcessor.java:486)
17:25:18,570 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor.inspect(OnDisconnectInterceptor.java:77)
17:25:18,572 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeInterceptors(AsynchronousProcessor.java:340)
17:25:18,572 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:199)
17:25:18,572 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:115)
17:25:18,572 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport.service(JBossWebCometSupport.java:93)
17:25:18,575 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281)
17:25:18,575 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.event(AtmosphereServlet.java:326)
17:25:18,575 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:494)
17:25:18,575 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:399)
17:25:18,576 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:273)
17:25:18,576 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
17:25:18,576 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
17:25:18,576 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
17:25:18,577 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
17:25:18,577 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
17:25:18,577 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
17:25:18,577 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
17:25:18,579 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897)
17:25:18,579 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634)
17:25:18,579 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039)
17:25:18,579 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:25:18,584 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) Locked: 0f2d436a-7e80-4a56-97e2-42187ac56a8b
17:25:18,584 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) java.lang.Exception
17:25:18,584 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$LockManagerBatch.<init>(DefaultLockManager.java:377)
17:25:18,585 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager.java:246)
17:25:18,585 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
17:25:18,585 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.channel.LockChannel.onClose(LockChannel.java:128)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.util.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:209)
17:25:18,586 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.invoke(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:335)
17:25:18,589 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(ManagedAtmosphereHandler.java:209)
17:25:18,589 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeAtmosphereHandler(AsynchronousProcessor.java:544)
17:25:18,589 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.completeLifecycle(AsynchronousProcessor.java:486)
17:25:18,589 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor.inspect(OnDisconnectInterceptor.java:77)
17:25:18,591 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.invokeInterceptors(AsynchronousProcessor.java:340)
17:25:18,591 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:199)
17:25:18,591 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:115)
17:25:18,591 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport.service(JBossWebCometSupport.java:93)
17:25:18,593 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281)
17:25:18,593 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.event(AtmosphereServlet.java:326)
17:25:18,593 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:494)
17:25:18,593 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilterEvent(ApplicationFilterChain.java:399)
17:25:18,595 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:273)
17:25:18,595 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
17:25:18,595 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
17:25:18,595 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
17:25:18,596 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
17:25:18,597 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
17:25:18,597 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
17:25:18,597 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
17:25:18,598 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897)
17:25:18,598 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634)
17:25:18,599 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039)
17:25:18,599 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Some seconds later the same thread handles more HTTP requests and all returned successfully, This time with the correct `Locked: xxx` and `Unlocked: xxx` messages:

```
17:25:23,891 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) Locked: 351e7416-c74b-4974-b2a6-a2ba0a0ad87d
17:25:23,892 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) java.lang.Exception
17:25:23,893 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$LockManagerBatch.<init>(DefaultLockManager.java:377)
17:25:23,894 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager.java:246)
17:25:23,896 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getManagerLock(DefaultLockManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
17:25:23,897 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.command.LockCommand.invoke(LockCommand.java:33)
17:25:23,898 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.PageLockCommandServlet._executeCommand(PageLockCommandServlet.java:90)
17:25:23,899 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.jee.pagelock.PageLockCommandServlet.doPost(PageLockCommandServlet.java:61)
17:25:23,900 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
17:25:23,900 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
17:25:23,901 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
17:25:23,901 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
17:25:23,901 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at xxx.webapp.servlet.filter.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:51)
17:25:23,902 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
17:25:23,902 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
17:25:23,903 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
17:25:23,903 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
17:25:23,903 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
17:25:23,904 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
17:25:23,904 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
17:25:23,904 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
17:25:23,905 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
17:25:23,905 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
17:25:23,905 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
17:25:23,906 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
17:25:23,906 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
17:25:23,906 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:897)
17:25:23,907 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:634)
17:25:23,907 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2039)
17:25:23,907 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17:25:23,908 INFO  [stdout] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13) Unlocked: 351e7416-c74b-4974-b2a6-a2ba0a0ad87d
```

Any idea what is going on? Can you explain to me how the very same thread can be executed again and again without fully executing the function body? Without releasing the lock?

**Edit 12.11.2015 19:56:** As mentioned in the comments: `http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13` is the name of the thread. So I'm sure that it is the same thread that is executed again.

**Edit 13.11.2015 09:38:** As mentioned in the comments: I'm using JBoss 7.1.3.Final with JBossWeb 7.0.17.Final. The AtmosphereServlet uses `asyncSupported=true` while the custom one doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure it's the "same thread executing again", and not a new thread, perhaps generated by another parallel request?

Comment: The thread comes from a thread pool which reuses the threads.  I think it is the same as the name stays the same for all calls. Additionally I print the `Locked` right after `lock()` and that won't be shown if it is a different thread.

Comment: you can check if it's the same guy, by also printing out `Thread.currentThread()`

Comment: I will add this to the log and try to reproduce it again. The error appears only sporadically. BTW: `http-/0.0.0.0:8080-13` is the name of the Thread.

Comment: ah - OK I hadn't realised that was the thread name!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question and added that piece of information.

Comment: You get exception in _lockManager.getManagerLock(true), in that case batchLock.unlock() will not executed.

Comment: It's mentioned in the initial posting, second paragraph: The exception is intended. I only display its stacktrace for debugging purposes. It doesn't interrupt the code execution.

Comment: At some point after DefaultLockManager.java:377 (the point you log the exception) but before returning and entering the try catch statement, that thread is getting reused.  I'm not familiar with the container you are using, but the stack traces that demo the issue show the use of the async servlet api, while the good stack trace does not.  I suspect some part of the async support is suspending the work on the thread, and using that thread to process another request (thus the new UUID).  If you let it live long enough, do they ever unlock?

Comment: You are right. Atmosphere uses `asyncSupported=true`. I'm using JBoss 7.1.3.Final with JBossWeb 7.0.17.Final. It is never unlocked and the requests hangs forever (till now ~16 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this behavior: A (CDI) bean was involved which couldn't be created for some reason. An exception was thrown after my log messages and before the try-block. But it was not visible in the log as the atmosphere framework caught it. The framework itself will only print it to the log if it is set to `debug` level (which is not set on the production server).

A really stupid self-caused bug!